# Windows 10: bash: behat: command not found error

Tags: php, composer-php, git-bash, behat

When I run `behat -v` (or any other Behat command) in Git bash I get the following error

> bash: behat: command not found

It works fine in the Windows command prompt.

I've tried installing Git with different options such as 'Use Git from Git Bash only', 'Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt', 'Use MinTTY', 'Use Windows default console window', but nothing has worked.

I installed Behat version 3.2.2 local to a project using Composer.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[INSTALLING BEHAT (WINDOWS 7)](http://autorobottesting.weebly.com/blog/installing-behat-windows-7)", make sure your `%PATH%` environment variable includes `C:\Behat\bin` in your CMD shell session.
And `<path\to\Git>\bin` (which includes `bash.exe`)

Then in that same shell, type `bash`: check that `behat` works.

Comment: Not sure if the question was updated, but the path you provided is not valid since is a local install for the project and since is local is not ok to use a global install to run since the config may differ :)

Comment: @lauda sure, replace `C:\Behat\bin` by whatever path `behat` was installed in. The idea remains the same: as long as your `%PATH%` references that `bin` folder, you are good to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am running Behat local to a project so adding it to the path environment variable is not necessary, as proven by the fact that it works fine in the cmd. Adding it to the path environment variable is only required if you want to use Behat from any location, which is not what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Behat from the location where is installed.

Navigate to the folder the Behat is installed (this should contain bin, vendor, composer.json etc) then open a command line there (any will do bash or cmd) and run Behat from there.

Use command for bash:

```
bin/behat -dl
```

Or for cmd:

```
bin\behat -dl
```

One last thing to check. Find your git shortcut, right click and check Properties->Shortcut tab and in the target you should have something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

Close and reopen git console and it should work.
To find the shortcut search git from start and then right click on Git Bash and click open file location.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am running Behat from the location it is installed. It works fine in the cmd, this indicates that Behat is successfully installed and I am in the correct location. Bash doesn't want to play nice.

Comment: Are you running from a tool like phpstorm?

Comment: Nope, not in this instance. I am running it strictly from the command line at this point.

Comment: It's weird as I have it working perfectly fine on my work computer. But on my home computer, it doesn't work in Bash. I could just use the cmd but I much prefer Bash. The only major difference between the two machines is that my work computer is running Windows 7 and my home computer is running Windows 10. I am going to test it with the same version of Git, when I get home this evening, to rule that out.

Comment: I see that on my W10 the path to git is C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd  and not \bin as expected and it works.

Comment: I'm going to have another go at solving it when I arrive home this evening. Again, thanks for your responses.